# create shortcut with Run As Administrator

Tags: python, arrays, powershell, byte, shortcut

im trying to create a shortcut that needs administrator privileges ... i found this code on the internet but its coded in powershell ... i test it its working !! but i need it in python how i can do the same with python

powershell code :

> Read the .lnk file in as an array of bytes. Locate byte 21 (0x15) and
>   change bit 6 (0x20) to 1. This is the RunAsAdministrator flag. Then
>   you write you byte array back into the .lnk file.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\ColorPix.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ColorPix\ColorPix.exe"
$Shortcut.Save()

$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\ColorPix.lnk")
$bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20 #set byte 21 (0x15) bit 6 (0x20) ON
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\ColorPix.lnk", $bytes)
```

this is my python code :

```
filename = r'C:\Users\root\Desktop\qassam.lnk'

with open(filename, "rb") as f2:

    while True:
      current_byte = f2.read(1)
      if (not current_byte):
        break
      val = ord(current_byte)
      q = hex(val)
      print q
```

i dont know what is the next step can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a library for editing `.lnk` files (not checked by me):

- https://github.com/libyal/liblnk
- https://pypi.org/project/pylnk/

Or emulate the behavior of your command using [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray)

```
filename = r'C:\Users\root\Desktop\qassam.lnk'

# $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\ColorPix.lnk")
with open(filename, "rb") as f2:
  ba = bytearray(f2.read())

# $bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20 #set byte 21 (0x15) bit 6 (0x20) ON
ba[0x15] = ba[0x15] | 0x20

# [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$Home\Desktop\ColorPix.lnk", $bytes)
with open(filename, "wb") as f3:
  f3.write(ba)
```

Comment: i got this error : 
    with open(filename, "wb") as f3:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Google Chrome.lnk'

Comment: @evilcode1 Could you try with a `.lnk` created by yourself? It would make sense to me that you don't have the rights to edit the chrome shortcut (which is what a virus would do)

Comment: solved thank u very much ....
can u explain what this line doing and what is | for ?? ( ba[0x15] = ba[0x15] | 0x20 )

Comment: @evilcode1 i've matched the lines with the lines of your powershell example. I hope it's all clear now

Answer (score 0):

This code generated the shortcut. But I didn't understand exactly what you wanted.

Code:

```
import os

def short(Shortcut_Path, _Path):
    Shortcut = """
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("{}")
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = "{}"
    $Shortcut.Save()""".format(Shortcut_Path, _Path)

    open("Shortcut.ps1", "w").write(Shortcut)
    os.system("Shortcut.ps1")
    os.remove("Shortcut.ps1")

short(os.environ["USERPROFILE"] + r"\Desktop\AIMP.lnk", r"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\AIMP\AIMP.exe")
```